# increase the size of radioButton in flex

Tags: apache-flex

Recently i worked in a project where i used 5 radio button to select a page number. Now the clients wants a big radio button. how can i increase the size of radio button in flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to target the button itself easily (perhaps through rawChildren?) but you can set scaleX and scaleY of the radiobutton. This will increase your label too, but that size can still be adjusted with fontsize.

Do keep in mind that this approach will give unexpected results when settings fontsize.